# Cannot add column inside a card below a row Flutter

Tags: flutter, card

I am implementing a card where I have rows, I want to add column below rows inside the card in flutter. I am unable to add column at the bottom inside the card.

```dart
Column buildWorkshopSection() {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Card(
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 5.0),
          clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
          color: Colors.white,
          elevation: 5.0,
          child: Padding(
            padding:
                const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0, vertical: 22.0),
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 5.0,
                      ),
                      buildStartTimeWorkshop(),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 5.0,
                      ),
                      buildCloseTimeWorkshop(),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
```

Comment: Add your UI sample screen here

Comment: https://imgur.com/4SLR8n0 i want to add save button insde card below start time and end time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add submit button like this

```
Card(
                      margin:
                          EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 5.0),
                      clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      elevation: 5.0,
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            horizontal: 8.0, vertical: 22.0),
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Row(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Expanded(
                                  child: Column(
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      SizedBox(
                                        height: 5.0,
                                      ),
                                      buildStartTimeWorkshop(),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Expanded(
                                  child: Column(
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      SizedBox(
                                        height: 5.0,
                                      ),
                                      buildCloseTimeWorkshop(),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 20,
                            ),
                            RaisedButton(
                              onPressed: () {},
                              child: Text("Submit"),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
```

It look like this

[image]

Comment: it shows me error, already tried but not works

Comment: just need to add a column below  rows

Comment: But it's work for me, What issue you faced, https://ibb.co/RCRx7yV

Comment: it does not allow me to add any thing inside card

Comment: @Ali Why using Column to display Start, End Time since you only have 1 row in the design pic you share? Btw, can you share the error here?

Comment: want to add more details, but not working,  just show red anything i add